# How can I recreate the Montgomery Inn "Cincinnati style" barbeque sauce at home?

Tags: sauce, restaurant-mimicry, barbecue-sauce

I love Montgomery Inn barbeque sauce for its tangy/vinegar-y flavor, however it's often not in stock at the stores in my area.

Does anyone know how I could achieve a similar flavor with a homemade sauce?

Comment: @user1575 - while we take requests for replicating recipes, we'd need a lot more detail on what this sauce is before we could do that.

Comment: I take it it's not related, in flavor, to the cinnamon flavors of Cincy chili?

Comment: Montgomery Inn sauce is a kansas city style sweet barbeque sauce.  I can't speak to what recipe would best mimic it - it's been a few years since I was there - but it looks like you can mail order it here: http://store.cincyfavorites.com/bbq-sauce-c28.aspx for a pretty reasonable price if you buy a lot.

Comment: Technically this isn't "restaurant" mimicry but our convention has been to use that tag for recipe recreations, so I've added it for general interest.  I've also edited out the "recipe request" language.

Comment: I found a comment on Yelp where one reviewer described the sauce as such: "It's tomato-based, thin, sweet, and must be warm to enjoy it fully. " - http://www.yelp.com/biz/montgomery-inn-boathouse-cincinnati#hrid:ZWqHvHU9nXRGkRDT-TO3IQ Maybe this helps figure out the correct ingredients/ratios a bit more.

Comment: Mmm - some pictures to slurp at  http://www.roadfood.com/Forums/Montgomery-Inn-Cincinnati-BBQ-pics-m436289.aspx

Comment: @chad nope, not even close. It's sweet and (vinegar) tangy, with some complex flavors I can't really put into words.

Answer (score 1):

Found this...

http://www.copykatchat.com/sauces/7118.htm

I've never been there, so I can't judge; but might be a good place to start.